# Convert Unicode to UTF-16 in PHP

Tags: php, unicode, utf-16

I have a unicode text that I need to convert to UTF-16.

The problem I have is, the unicode text is saved in the database in UFT-16 format. Now I need to run a search query, but the POST data is bringing the actual unicode to the parameter. So I need to convert it to UTF-16 format to run the search query.

**The unicode text I am trying to search/convert** - `基本的`

**How the text is saved in the database** - `\u57fa\u672c\u7684\u306a\u8105\u5a01\u4fdd\u8b77`

I have tried the following code which I extracted from StackOverflow but nothing seems to work.

```
if (strlen($value) != strlen(utf8_decode($value))) {
   $c = unpack('N', mb_convert_encoding($value, 'UCS-4BE', 'UTF-8')); // returns an array [42]
   $d = mb_check_encoding($value,"UTF-8"); // returns true
   $e = utf8_encode($value); // returns *åŸºæœ¬çš„*
   $f = mb_convert_encoding($value, 'UCS-4BE', 'UTF-16'); // returns some weird characters (stackoverflow even doesn't allow to post the question with it)
}
```

Does someone have an idea how to do this conversion or any alternative paths I can take to complete the search?

Comment: UTF-16 *is* Unicode. What encoding do you have and what encoding do you want? That's the first thing to find out! Also, take the [tour] and read [ask], because "nothing seems to work" is not a good problem description. Further, provide a [mcve] and precise info what you expect and what you get, not just your "it doesn't work" interpretation.

Comment: Note: encoding means that you create a binary data. You need to have a tool which read such encoding. If you convert to UTF-16, you should read (and print) the result as UTF16. If your webpage or console is UTF-8 (or maybe just Latin1), you get garbage.

Comment: What you are showing here is all UTF-8. The DB code \u57fa\u672c\u7684\u306a\u8105\u5a01\u4fdd\u8b77 treated with json_encode results in "基本的な脅威保護" (pure UTF8).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jspit mentioned in comments, `\u57fa\u672c\u7684\u306a\u8105\u5a01\u4fdd\u8b77` is the `json_encode` representation of `基本的な脅威保護`.

I was able to get the original UTF-8 representation using `json_decode`.